# Can we make it impossible for the asker to delete a question which has at least one answer (no matter the upvotes)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deletion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

There are multiple questions on meta about users deleting their question right after receiving an answer, before this answer can be upvoted.

See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/people-who-ask-homework-questions-and-then-remove-them) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/why-do-some-users-delete-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer)

I don't see any reason to leave this 'window of opportunity'. No one benefits from it, except for dishonest people.

If an answer left is not relevant to the question and the OP has noticed that the question is bad and wants to delete it, then they can just flag the answer for moderator's attention and wait until it's deleted. Or even edit the question since no relevant answers were given yet.

If the answer is on point, then it's not the answerer's fault that the OP changed their mind.

> Do you agree that the deletion of answered questions by the asker should not be allowed?

Comment: In [another discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/is-there-a-way-to-punish-users-for-posting-and-then-immediately-deleting-a-quest) this meta.SE feature request was linked: [Preventing misuse of question self-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/preventing-misuse-of-question-self-deletion).

Comment: It's not necessarily dishonest to delete your question, even after getting an answer. I've deleted my own answered questions because I didn't like the reception. You could argue that the majority of questions are homework problems, but what about people like me who have never asked for help with homework in their lives and just want to learn something?

Comment: @Matt, we're going a bit off-topic here, but I would say that once someone answers your question, you are no longer the only person with an investment in that question, and to delete the question without the approval of the user or users who have answered is an insult to that user or users. There are other ways to express your dislike of the reception a question of yours gets.

Comment: I second Gerry on this, perhaps the OP may not have a need, but someone on the site thought the question was good enough to receive an answer, and that could be of use to others. Now on the other hand, I think @MattSamuel brings up a good point with reception. While the first goal here of course is to learn and share knowledge, this is STILL a digital profile that we have. And messy questions, filled with not-so-nice comments etc... may be something we want to distance ourselves from. In that case, instead of "deleting" a question, there should be a way to disconnect accounts from questions.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/is-there-a-way-to-punish-users-for-posting-and-then-immediately-deleting-a-quest?noredirect=1&lq=1 also is an interesting conundrum

Comment: @frog, that's the first link in Martin's comment.

Comment: In this context it might be worth mentioning that you can find *your own* deleted answers after reaching 10k; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers) for details.

Comment: Wow, this is so naive. Have you ever seen how question deletion *actually* plays out in practice? e.g. Sometimes people's questions just keep getting downvoted for whatever reason, and then someone posts a stupid "answer" that entirely misses the subtlety that's the crux of the question. So the OP just wants to delete it and doesn't see it being worth saving (if even possible -- sometimes too many downvotes just make it hard). Now you're saying they *have* to keep it on there and take a constant beating instead of just being able to delete it already?

Comment: @Mehrdad, questions do not "take a beating" for no reason. Once the reason is explained in the comments, you are free to edit! Moreover, if the answer is "stupid", just flag it and wait for moderator's intervention. Even if you get something like -100 (which is impossible, unless your question is really bad), once the "stupid" answer is deleted you are free to delete your question and get all the reputation back. Maybe before calling me naive you actually look at my own questions and answers. I have posts with negative or zero score, and I keep them because they are important to me.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: They take beatings for reasons besides quality. They take beatings because some people's egos get bruised by not knowing an answer. They take beatings because people don't *like* that a question is doing something unorthodox, even when it's perfectly written. They take beatings because some think anything they don't care about is "too localized". *This* is why I ask if you've seen reality. And "just flag it and wait for moderator's intervention"? Since *when* have you seen moderators delete answers that look right from the outside but entirely miss the point of the question?

Comment: @Mehrdad, see my other meta question by the way

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Which one? I don't see any by you linked here.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Huh? What does this have to do with the *answers* exploiting something in the question? I'm talking about *downvoters* beating down the OP....

Comment: @Mehrdad, anyway, I have never seen multiple downvotes for no reason. You obviously feel strongly about this, but I feel strongly about people deleting their homework questions right after getting an answer

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Like I said, it's *not* getting downvotes for "no reason", it's just getting them for stupid reasons. If only I'd been writing down the URLs of all the ones I'd seen to show people like you... but things just don't necessarily work the way you think they do. The closest thing I can dig up for you is [one meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231245/154726) made back in 2013 when this was starting to escalate. It's about close-votes, but still, read it. People agree that bandwagons happen & votes become biased. Downvotes are similar, though you probably won't believe me...

Comment: What about research-sensitive contexts?  I understand that we mathematicians (as a discipline) have less of a problem with results being 'scooped' than other sciences, but it can definitely still happen.

I suppose my contention here pertains to people who want to ask a research related question to receive some insight, but then feel that leaving the question up with all of its gory details (as well as the answer) may allow someone else to swoop in on a result they're trying to prove.

Comment: @AlecRhea, that's for Math Overflow. Math.SE is not for research. Besides, it would be absolutely dishonest to recieve some help with your research and then delete both the question and the answer, with intent to use it later. What about the person who answered?

Comment: On what grounds would you call it dishonest?  It is very common in a research setting to seek advice from a colleague on a small part of your research without giving them authorship; a mention in the bibliography is customary if it was a small but significant piece of the work.  Getting a question answered on Overflow strikes me as very similar, so deleting the question and mentioning the answer-er in your bibliography doesn't strike me as underhanded at all -- you just aren't leaving it out there for anyone else to scoop up before you publish.

Comment: @AlecRhea, the premise of this post is that the askers delete questions with no warning to the answerer, leaving them with no access to their own work. Do you see what I mean here?

Comment: @YuriyS: You said, «if the answer is "stupid", just flag it and wait for moderator’s intervention.»  Moderators generally do not delete questions just because they are wrong.

Comment: @Scott, I was talking about answers, you commented about questions, I don't get it. And I'm talking about not-answers or off-topic answers, or even rude answers. Whether or not the answer is wrong should be judged by the community.

Comment: @YuriyS: OK, I mistyped. I meant to say, "Moderators generally do not delete ***answers*** just because they are wrong.  Mehrdad was referring to «a stupid "answer" that entirely misses the subtlety that's the crux of the question.»; that would not necessarily be NAA, VLQ, OT or rude.

Comment: That sure sounds like an annoying thing to have happen to you, but it's part and parcel of being online.

Answer (score 3):

I am in favor of this proposal. While moderators currently do not generally delete answers for being wrong, it would seem reasonable for moderators to respond to requests to delete a *question/answer pair* by request of OP when the answer is mediocre and the question is bad (or more precisely, when the moderator determines that the QA pair does not have lasting value). In other words, for the "default case" we do not allow self deletion of answered questions, but the moderators can override this in cases when the self-deletion is justified.

Answer (score 2):

No. If it is a question got a lot of downvotes because it was not well formulated, had a bad format, is unclear, ..., then I think it is better the question is deleted than it survives. My experience is that most of he poster of bad questions will not put any effort to improve the question if it is already answered. 
I think the chances that a good  upvoted question will be deleted are  rather small.

Comment: I feel this answer misses the point a bit. The proposal is about selfdeletes only.

Comment: So why should the person who answered loose access to their own post with no warning?

Comment: @quid yes I know. I think it is better to remove a bad question than leave it unimproved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I can kind of see your point. But I think it only concerns a few corner cases.